# Error propagation for sine function, in terms of degrees and radians

Tags: error-propagation

For a measurement $\theta$ with uncertainty $\Delta\theta$, the propagated error of the sine function is given by

$$\Delta(\sin\theta) = (\cos\theta)\cdot\Delta\theta$$

However I note that if $\theta$ is given in terms of radians and degrees, $\Delta\theta$ will be scaled accordingly.

i.e.
$$\Delta(\sin\theta_{radian}) = (\cos\theta_{radians})\cdot\Delta\theta_{radians}$$

$$\Delta(\sin\theta_{degrees}) = (\cos\theta_{degrees})\cdot\Delta\theta_{degrees}$$

Which gives different values of error for $\Delta(\sin\theta)$

How should the error of propagation be evaluated? Is the convention for it to be evaluated in radians?

Comment: Radians should be used. Note: this had nothing to do with error function

Comment: @YuriyS, can I ask if this is by convention?

Comment: no, radians are the natural measure of the angle. Only for the radians the approximation $\sin x \approx x$ holds for $x<<1$. Degrees are just arbitrary, they do not have any mathematical significance

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is approximating $f(x+h)-f(x) \approx f'(x)h$.

If $f(x) = \sin x$ then $f(x+h)-f(x) \approx (\cos x) h$.

If $f(x) = \sin ({\pi \over 180} x)$, then $f(x+h)-f(x) \approx {\pi \over 180}(\cos ({\pi \over 180} x)) h$.

The third formula in the question is incorrect.